# Is it possible to add a delay to the remove class part of toggleClass only?

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

Is it possible to add a delay to the remove class part of toggleClass only?

In the fiddle, I would like the red div to turn green instantly when clicked.
But it should delay in turning back to red when clicked again.

http://jsfiddle.net/simbasounds/ggk8xxya/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   I am a div
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
}

.container.green {
    background: green;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".container").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('green');
});
```

Comment: why dont you use a css3 animation with a timing? seems like a little bit more work but less hacky

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/. `toggleClass` can accept a function and a state so you could write it yourself.

Comment: @simbasounds...delay as in you want fadeEffect when converting from green to red or just a simple time delay?

Comment: @bhavya_w simple time delay, no fade.

Comment: @Alex's suggestion could work. I hadn't thought of adding a CSS transition to .container.green only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Simple Time Delay while converting from green to red

```
$(".container").click(function(){
   var $element = $(this);

   //check if element has green class --> remove green class with a delay
   if ($element.hasClass('green')) {
     var delay = 1000; //ms
     setTimeout(function(){
         $element.removeClass('green');
     },delay );
   }
   // element doesn't have green class --> add it
   else {
     $element.addClass('green');
   }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggk8xxya/2/)

Answer (score 2):

What about the obvious way?

```
$(".container").click(function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass('green')) {
     // add your delay here
   }
   else {
     $(this).toggleClass('green');
   }
});
```